# Save images in iOS app which are loaded once when internet connection is available

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am creating a app in which i am saving some user detail and their messages, This app works similar to Facebook or many other i mean first time data come from api's and then i will store it in our local database. So the data which is loaded once is store in local database and user can see it without internet connection. I have store messages and detail in sqlite database it works fine with text messages and save detail of user.

The Problem is that i want to save profile image with user detail in local storage, i don't want to save it in database but save it into app directory for that i am using this below code

```
        UIImageView *ProfileImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 1, 30, 30)];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
            NSData *imageData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ton.hiitap.com/p/%@",[TOUSERUDID objectAtIndex:i]]]];


            NSString *imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.png",[TOUSERUDID objectAtIndex:i] ]];
            [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
            UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
            NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d.png",[TOUSERUDID objectAtIndex:i],i]]; //Add the file name
            [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

            pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
            UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                ProfileImage.image=img2;
            });
        });
```

The Problem with this code is it only save 2 users profile image and the images which are repeated are not shown when no internet connection is available. Can anyone suggest how to save all users profile images even they are repeated. So that they are shown when no internet connection is available. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using core data you can create a column for example userImage with the type NSData in your user model
 and you can convert you image to NSData like this :

**if PNG image** :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

**if JPG image** :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

and you can load the image from the database like this :

```
NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self yourFetchCOntroller] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"image"]];
// and set this image in to your image View  
    yourimageView.image=image;
```